Change of variable for probability density involving unphysical region
I'm trying to convert a probability density function (PDF) of a squared variable $Y^2$ that includes non-physical values into a PDF for the variable $Y$. The pdf of $Y^2$, which represents a physical quantity, has been approximated as a Gaussian function with mean $\mu=1$ and standard deviation $\sigma=1.5$ which extends to negative $Y^2$ values.
I proceeded as follows but I'm not sure if this approach is correct, so any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
First, I removed the unphysical region and normalized the part of the PDF corresponding to $Y^2>0$ to 1 (I assumed a flat prior for $Y^2>0$). Then, I applied a change of variable $Y^2 \rightarrow Y$ taking into account the Jacobian factor $2Y$. I attach two figures showing the PDFs for $Y^2$

and $Y$

As you can see, due to the Jacobian factor, the PDF of $Y$, unlike that of $Y^2$, goes to 0 as $Y \rightarrow 0$. This makes me a bit skeptical. However, the credible intervals appear to be consistent between the two PDFs, and if the pdf of $Y^2$ is assumed to be correct why would the one for $Y$ be wrong?
Thanks a lot for any advice or insights.

What you have observed is that if the pdf for a positive random variable $X$ is bounded  when $x \to 0^+$ then the pdf for $\sqrt{X} \to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$.

Thanks, this means that what I did is correct, isn’t it?

Yes.  As a check, trying the R simulation X <- rnorm(10^6,1,1.5) can roughly reproduce your charts with plot(density(X[X>0],from=0,to=8)) and plot(density(sqrt(X[X>0]),from=0,to=5)) though whether using a truncated Gaussian to model the square of a variable makes sense physically is a different question.
